# Update an another field along with the increment_counter method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord

I have a cache_counter field on my Customer model which is *orders_count*. This field can be only update using the increment_counter method.
`Customer.increment_counter(:orders_count, customer_id)` this will increment the orders count of the customer. There is an another field which is already in my Customer model that is *last_updated_at* , i want to update this field along the increment_counter method.
How this could be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`increment_counter`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter) method accepts a third, optional argument that allows to update timestamp columns. Therefore you can just change your method call to:

```
Customer.increment_counter(:orders_count, customer_id, touch: :last_updated_at)
```

Comment: what will be the value assigned in :last_updated_at, because I need Time.now() as the value.

Comment: It will assign `Time.now` in the same timezone our application uses for `created_at` or `updated_at` columns which is usually UTC

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to set the tiemstamp in `last_updated_at`, you can use the `touch` option in the `belongs_to` association for your orders. Something like,

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer, touch: :last_updated_at
end
```

You can read more about it [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-touch)